# What makes bathroom soap bars to crack during winter season?

Tags: water, home-experiment, surface-tension

Is there some relation between winter season and cracking of bathroom soaps? I noticed that , cracking happens only during winter season.I also learned earlier from physics stack that, During winter air becomes more dry and that causes lot of static electric discharges. Does the cracking got anything to do with dryness of air?can somebody guide me to do experiment to verify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because when the soap dries it shrinks, like a sponge, river mud, or cloth, because the remaining water has surface tension pulling the material together. It dries from the outside in, so the differential shrinkage causes stress, so the material cracks.
I doubt if it has anything to do with static electricity.

There are ways to dry things without shrinkage, as in the manufacture of [*aerogels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel).

Comment: Mike Dunlavey, is there a way i can do an experiment to confirm your hypothesis?

Comment: @nemu: Just guessing - put a bar of soap in a cool oven? Travel to the nearest dry lake or river bed?